# <td> does not display full contents (Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: firefox, html-table

*The code goes like this*

```
<div id='blogbook'></div>
...
<script>
...
var z="<table>
<td>Blog title and date<br><hr></td>
<tr>
<td>A very long string consisting of many paragraphs, say, a blog</td></table>";
function disp(){
document.getElementById('blogbook').innerHTML=z;
}
disp();
</script>
```

*The display comes out like this..*

Blog title and date

---

A very long string consisting of
...(many many lines)...
many paragraphs, sa

The whole of the blog does not display, instead stops long before the actual end of the blog. 
Questions:

- Why does this happen?
- How does one solve this?

  This problem occurs in Firefox(I'm using v7 but IE displays it just fine, that is, the complete blog)

Comment: You probably have invalid html. Try running it through a validator.

Comment: Every time one does not close a html tag a baby seal dies :(

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. I failed to realize that its not an HTML issue. Rather its one about JS chopping XML nodes into multiple nodes of size 4kiB and lazy me printing only the `firstChild.data` (the first node). Thank you for your answers anyway. I do have some experience in HTML and wouldn't have posted if it was as simple a problem like invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is incorrect.

```
var z="<table>
<td>Blog title and date<br><hr></td>
<tr>
<td>A very long string consisting of many paragraphs, say, a blog</td></table>";
```

That code is this:

```
<table>
    <td>Blog title and date<br><hr></td>
  <tr>
    <td>A very long string consisting of many paragraphs, say, a blog</td>
</table>
```

It should be:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blog title and date<br><hr></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A very long string consisting of many paragraphs, say, a blog</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nope, I tried, that's not it. Its not something that simple, I'm afraid. Somehow Ff has put a limit on how big the string `var z` can be. Many of my blogs are 5k-6k characters long. However, the <td> shows only about 4076 characters. But this problem doesn't happen with IE. Any clue why <td> is displaying only about 4kiB of data?

Answer (score 0):

whats going on with this line `<div id='blogbook'></td>`?  You need to close the div.  its not semantically correct and may cause the browser to display incorrectly e.g

```
<div id='blogbook'></div></td>
```

Plus your not closing the table above or your not opening a new td if your nesting tables